# How to select child contour in OpenCV and increase accuracy using python

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, object-detection, contour

I'm really new to OpenCV. :) I have been working on this for almost an entire day. After hours of sleepless work I would like to know if I can further improve my code.

I have written some code to **select only the black markings** on [the images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WCLpx7HbmzR5zmVocIvWAbaCVl16v9P1?usp=sharing). These black markings are child contours. Whilst my code is able to select some contours, it isn't accurate. You can see the code *draws contours around the shadows* along with black markings.

**Code 1**

At first I tried to use canny edge detection. But I was unable to overlay with the original image correctly.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('3.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (500, 500))
image2 = image
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find Canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.imshow('Canny', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))

cv2.drawContours(image2, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow('Contours', image2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: The original image and contours]

**Code 2**

I was able to improve on Code 1 to be far more accurate. You should be able to see that it now only selects half of the thumb, none of the other fingers and it doesn't select the indent on the background.
Additionally changing the background of the image also increases the accuracy of the result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('3.jpg', 0)
image2 = cv2.imread('3.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (500, 500))
image2 = cv2.resize(image2, (500, 500))
cv2.waitKey(0)

ret, thresh_basic = cv2.threshold(image, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("Thresh basic", thresh_basic)

# Taking a matrix of size 5 as the kernel
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

img_erosion = cv2.erode(thresh_basic, kernel, iterations=1)

#####################

ret, thresh_inv = cv2.threshold(img_erosion, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("INV", thresh_inv)
#####################




# Find Canny edges

edged = cv2.Canny(img_erosion, 30, 200)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.imshow('Canny', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))
cv2.imshow('Original', image2)
cv2.drawContours(image2, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)


cv2.imshow('Contours', image2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
[image]

Can I improve my code further?

Comment: Threshold the image so that your black markings are black on a white background. Use morphology to clean up extraneous markings. The invert the thresholded image, so that the black markings are white on a black background and then find the external contours of those. External contours are generally found around white objects not black ones.

Comment: @fmw42 so first I need to do `adaptiveThreshold` ?

Comment: Whichever type of threshold that best separates the black from the rest of the image. Please always post original input images and if more than one, do them separately. That way other people can demonstrate or modify your code for you. Do not post screen snaps or multiple images in one image.

Comment: @fmw42, noted! I'll attach the original images